# ¿Cómo cambiar el color del texto de un input en PHP dependiendo de lo que reciba de una consulta en Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tengo la siguiente tabla en mi base de datos

> notas

[image: db]

Y esta es mi PHP con la tabla donde se me muestran

> notas.php

[image: notas]

```
    <table class="table table-hover" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<td><b>RUT</b></td>
<td><b>Nombre</b></td>
<td><b>Apellido</b></td>
<td><b>Notas</b></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "","liceo");
if (!$connect) {
die(mysqli_error());
}
$results = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT rut, nombre, apellido FROM alumnos");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($results)) {
$rut = $row->rut;
$boo = 0; /* Iniciamos la Variable Auxiliar
          que indicará cuantas notas se imprimió  por cada Alumno  */
$results2 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT nota FROM notas WHERE rut_alumno = '$rut' LIMIT 4");
?>
<tr>
<td><?=$row->rut?></td>
<td><?=$row->nombre?></td>
<td><?=$row->apellido?></td>
<td>
<?php
while($nota = mysqli_fetch_object($results2)):
?>


 <input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="2" size="2" value="<?=$nota->nota?>" style="color: <?php echo $color; ?>">

<?php
    $boo +=1;/* Incrementamos después de Imprimir la nota del Alumno*/
endwhile;
/* Si la variable es menor a 2 , es decir no se imprimieron las 2 notas respectivas*/
if($boo<4){ 
    /* Imprimimos  inputs de value 0 hasta que sea < 2 , dado que si el
    el valor de $boo es 1 o 0 , primero se realizará el echo y luego el incremento
    Sí $boo es 0 -> Iteración 0 - Imprime el input - Incrementa $boo -> $boo = 1
                    Iteración 1 - Imprime el input - Incrementa $boo -> $boo = 2
                    Termina el for dado que 2 no es menor que 2
    Sí $boo es 1 -> Iteración 0 - Imprime el input - Incrementa $boo -> $boo = 2
                    Termina el For dado que 2 no es menor que 2
     */
    for (; $boo < 4; $boo++) { 
        echo '<input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="2" size="2" value="10">';
    }
}
?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php
  }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer una consulta para establecer que si la nota es igual o mayor a 4, esté de color azul, y si es menor a 4 color de rojo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la pregunta tal cual está en el momento de responder, con la información dada, entiendo que quieres cambiar el color del *número* dentro del `input`cada vez que se realiza la consulta.

Una solución sencilla sería usar [operadores ternarios](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

```
//...
<?php 
while($nota = mysqli_fetch_object($results2)):
$color = ($nota->nota >= 4)? '#0000ff' : '#ff0000'; #<-- solo tienes que añadir esta línea
?>
<input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="2" size="2" 
       value="<?=$nota->nota?>" style="color: <?php echo $color; ?>">
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es que según se escriba la nota en el input, ésta y no toda la fila u otra cosa queden de color rojo o azul en función de su valor.

Desde PHP no puedes hacerlo porque la petición se hace una vez enviados los datos, así que no te queda más remedio que meter un pequeño script en javascript para que haga esta labor dentro del mismo input.

```
    <table class="table table-hover" border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td><b>RUT</b></td>
          <td><b>Nombre</b></td>
          <td><b>Apellido</b></td>
          <td><b>Notas</b></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
          $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "liceo");

          if (!$connect) {
            die(mysqli_error());
          }

          $results = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT rut, nombre, apellido FROM alumnos");

          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($results)) {
            $rut = $row->rut;
            $boo = 0; /* Iniciamos la Variable Auxiliar
            que indicará cuantas notas se imprimió  por cada Alumno  */
            $results2 = mysqli_query($connect,
              "SELECT nota FROM notas WHERE rut_alumno = '$rut' LIMIT 4"
            );
        ?>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <?php echo $row->rut ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $row->nombre ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $row->apellido ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php
                  while ($nota = mysqli_fetch_object($results2)):
                ?>

                <input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="2" size="2"
                  value="<?php echo $nota->nota ?>"
                  style="color: <?php echo $color; ?>"
                >

                <?php
                    $boo+= 1;
                  endwhile;
                  if ($boo < 4) {
                    for (; $boo < 4; $boo++) {
                      echo '<input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="2" size="2" value="10">';
                    }
                  }

                ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }

        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

La idea sería ir mirando cada vez que desaparezca el focus del input (por ejemplo) cambiar el color según el valor, para:
Rojo < 4
Azul >= 4

Por lo tanto:

```
    <input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="2" size="2"
      value="<?php echo $nota->nota ?>"

      onblur="
        function() {
          var inputs = document.getElementsByName('pin');
          var i, color;
          for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { 
            color = "blue";
            if inputs[i].value < 4 {
              color = "red";
            }
            inputs[i].style.color = color;
          }
        }()
      "
    >
```

Comment: Valoro mucho tu guía. No me está tomando el código, intenté asociarlo a un script y no logré que me funcionara, sabes por qué podrá ser?

Comment: Podría ser el scope del this.
Puedes probar poniéndole nombre a cada nota o una clase, y cambiarlas todas cada vez que hay un blur.

Comment: Lo edité para encontrar los elementos sin this.